# Clojure server-socket ClassNotFoundException error

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I'm trying to test [mire](https://github.com/technomancy/mire).

When I execute this code

```
(ns mire
  (:use [clojure.contrib server-socket duck-streams]))
```

I have `java.io.FileNotFoundException` error.

Googling to find that `clojure.contrib` is deprecated, I added server-socket as dependencies in the `project.clj`, and executed `leon repl` to install the jar libraries

```
mire> lein repl
Retrieving server-socket/server-socket/1.0.0/server-socket-1.0.0.pom from clojars
Retrieving server-socket/server-socket/1.0.0/server-socket-1.0.0.jar from clojar
```

Then in the emacs/cider, I tried to use this code to get the same FileNotFoundException error.

```
(ns mire
  (:use [server.socket server-socket duck-streams]))

java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate server/socket/server_socket__init.class or     
server/socket/server_socket.clj on class path:
```

In command line REPL, `(use [server.socket server-socket])` gives me the same error message.

What might be wrong? I use emacs/cider/nREPL. This is the project.clj.

```
(defproject mire "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [server-socket "1.0.0"]])
```

This is the code that causes an error:

```
(ns mire
  (:use [clojure.contrib server-socket duck-streams]))

(def port (* 3 1111))

(defn mire-handle-client [in out]
  (binding [*in* (reader in)
            *out* (writer out)]
    (loop []
      (println (read-line))
      (recur))))

(def server (create-server port mire-handle-client))
```

Comment: There is no server-socket namespace. It's `server.socket`. Also, you should be using :require, not :use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code in [Building an Echo Server in Clojure - Part 2](http://angeleah.com/blog/2012/11/20/building-an-echo-server-in-clojure---part-2.html), this is the working code with `server.socket`.

```
(ns mire
  (:use server.socket))
(import '[java.io BufferedReader InputStreamReader OutputStreamWriter])

(def port (* 3 1111))

(defn mire-handle-client [in out]
  (binding [*in* (BufferedReader. (InputStreamReader. in))
            *out* (OutputStreamWriter. out)]
        (loop []
            (println (read-line))
            (recur))))

(def server (create-server port mire-handle-client))
```

Answer (score 1):

The namespaces are usually dot-separated. `server.socket` in this library is.

Try this:

```
(ns mire (:use [server.socket]))
```